# swift: cannot subscript a value of type [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] with an index of type string

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I am trying to json parsing in swift 3. I am getting the above mentioned error. My parsing technique is as follows:

```
if let responseData = data {
   do {
     let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
     if let dict = json as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
        if let localityName = dict["name"] as? String ,let localityId = dict["_id"] as? String {

         }               
     }           
   } catch {
       print("could not serialize")            
   }
}
```

I am getting the error in the line:

```
if let localityName = dict["name"] as? String ,let localityId = dict["_id"] as? String
```

please let me know how can I fix this issue

Comment: You are creating an `Array` of `Dictionary`'s. Is this valid. You need to `subscript` it with `Int` values.

Comment: @New16 My response is an array of dictionaries

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 My response is an array of dictionaries

Comment: `[Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]` => Array (of dictionaries). But when you do `dict["name"]`, you use `dict` as a dict, but not as an array as you set declared it before. That's why you have the error. If you response is a array of dictionaries, clearly, call it `array`, not `dict`, that's so confusing. And access its value differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dict` is actually `arr`. Create a loop to iterate thru it

```
if let arr = json as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
   for item in arr {
      if let localityName = item["name"] as? String,
         let localityId = item["_id"] as? String {
         print(localityName, localityId)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` property is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary.
You could access the first elements name the following:

```
dict.first?["name"]
```